# msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory data gets deleted whenever SQL Server services are restarted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am facing an issue where my `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` data is getting deleted whenever my SQL Server services are restarted or the instance fails over.

I am using SQL Server 2014 SP2 in a cluster environment, with below SQL Agent History setting:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest what the issue is?

Comment: What's History setting in SQL Server Agent?

Comment: @AdityaSawant, What is SQL Server version(x,y,z)?

Comment: How much job history you want to retain? Is it for a certain time for all jobs or each job has specific retention time?

Comment: @Md Haidar Ali Khan, My SQL Server version is SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU11)

Comment: Could you please post a screen shot of your **SQL Server Agent Properties - History** settings? I am requesting a screen shot, because my own installation only accepts a value of `2` for **Maximum job history log size (in rows)** and **Maximum job history rows per job**.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use I have updated by Post with SQL Agent History scree shot

Answer (score 0):

My response is based on possible reasons of problem.
Make sure you have configured History setting properly and the job to purge history scheduled properly. To validate these settings:

Right click on **SQL Server Agent** and got to **Properties**.

[image]

Go to **History** tab.

[image]

Make sure setting is configured properly.

[image]

The job named **syspolicy_purge_history** used to execute above settings.

So right click on the job in Jobs folder in SQL Server Agent and check Schedule of the Job.

[image]

It should be scheduled according to your requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen my sql Agent history settings and it is not set to any limited size also my syspolicy_purge_history job is set to recurring schedule which does not deletes all the history of all jobs but when my sql server is restarted all my job history are deleted .

Comment: Please validate other jobs executes on start of SQL Server Agent.

Comment: I have validate all other jobs on my SQL Server No jobs execute on start of SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Possibly someone has added a stored procedure and marked it to run on startup 

you can identify these with this query, check in the master database


SELECT [name]
FROM sysobjects
WHERE type = 'P'
  AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'ExecIsStartUp') = 1